# Extracting ACL support in Yammer REST api

Tags: acl, yammer

Is there any support in Yammer REST Api for extracting ACLs (Access control list) of the logged in user. Like what if I want to know that the given message is accessible to the given user or some group containing this user.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to get an ACL exactly, but depending on how your app works, you may be able to get the answer you need. If you a verified admin of the Yammer network has authenticated with your app, then you can use the Impersonation API https://developer.yammer.com/docs/impersonation to impersonate the user in question and then simply attempt to access the given resource. If the response is a 401, then the user doesn't have access.

Comment: 0
down vote
accept
Okay, What if I logged in with say admin user who has access to all the contents in one domain and When I am crawling yammer through that user, How can I get that ACLs of that particular message or post ?

Coz Since I am logged in as an admin user so will I be able to access the ACLs of the given doc or content that I am crawling or I will have to impersonate for each and every user residing the given domain of yammer?

Comment: Coming at it from the object side, it's important to know that there are two types of Yammer messages: group messages and private messages

Private messages are pretty easy in that the API response includes the list of users who have access as "invited_user_ids".

For group threads, individual users don't have access, groups have access. The group ID is provided in the API response. You could attempt to get the group member list at any point in time (undocumented) but that would just be a snapshot as group membership changes frequently.

Comment: Also, note that users from outside of a group or outside of a Yammer network can be added to group messages, as documented here: developer.yammer.com/docs/external-participants.